# UITableview dynamic height adjustment in UITableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, ios-autolayout

i am using `UITableview` in `UITableviewCell`.

i have problem to set height of `UITableview` in `UITableViewCell`, but initially height can not adjust according to content size of `UITableview` but when `UITableview` reloads or dequeue then tableview height in `UITablevieWCell` adjust automatically.

i want to adjust this height as first time.

Below is my code for review in tableview `cellForRowAt` delegate method.

```
cell.tableviewShow.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
cell.tableviewShow.tag = indexPath.row

cell.tableviewShow.reloadData()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.heightOfTbleView.constant = cell.tableviewShow.contentSize.height
cell.tableviewShow.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: do you have `TableView` inside `TableViewCell`?

Comment: @AmirKhan Yes. He want to resize the outer tableview cell to fit content size of inner tableview

Comment: @RajeshKumarR exactly

Answer (score -1):

For Dynamic height in cell use  :

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension  
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
```